# Magento 2, add Custom Text Attribute to the Products

Tags: custom-attributes

I add a Custom TEXT Attribute (more_info) to my Magento 2 Store and I will show the Value to my product.info.main Page.

I add

**mytheme\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" template="product/view/more_info.phtml" >
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

and

**mytheme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\more_info.phtml**

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
    <?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('more_info') ?>
```

but they show me no value:-(

I'm very thankful for any help.

Comment: try with   <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/more_info.phtml" >

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this changes,

Change your xml like this,

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/more_info.phtml"></block>
</referenceBlock>
```

And modify your phtml file :

```
mytheme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\more_info.phtml


<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('more_info') ?>
```

OR

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('more_info')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>
```

Comment: the .xml is correct, they show me some test text from the phtml file but the attribute value is not showing with your phtml code.

Comment: verify that you have set attribute value for that product in admin.

Comment: I update my answer, you can also try another way I mension.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use like this

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/more_info.phtml"></block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: the .xml is correct thanks, i see some test text from the phtml file but the attribute value is missing.

Comment: Check this blog. http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://www.dckap.com/blog/display-custom-attribute-value-product-viewlist-page-magento-2/&ei=CEDEWpJ8&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=398&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1482428094&sig=AF9NedkFY5XyBx3E04DuKD7M3iNpOhJ-Vg